# ElasticSearch not showing correct results for exactmatch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to search for an exact match string but ES does not give me expected results.

Below is the example -

Here is index creation -

```
POST /spacetesting1
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "couchbaseDocument" : {
            "_source" : { "enabled" : false },
            "properties" : {
                "name" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below are the 2 documents I inserted to the index -

```
PUT /spacetesting1/CouchbaseDocument/7
{
  "name": "new york"
}

PUT /spacetesting1/CouchbaseDocument/8
{
  "name": "new York company"
}
```

When I search for a word 'new york', ES gives me 2 documents as above. But I am expecting only one that is exact match with 'new york'.

Can someone guide me on how to get exact match from ES?

Thanks in advance.

Regard,
Sameer

Comment: And how are you doing the search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it is a case issue. In mapping you gave 'couchbaseDocument' and while indexing he gave CouchbaseDocument.

Comment: Seems it is a case issue. In mapping he gave 'couchbaseDocument' and while indexing he gave CouchbaseDocument

Comment: Vineeth - You are right. 'Type' was case sensitive. I received a single document matching with search after correcting the type.